# Python: Iterate two lists, to unify string from column 1 with column 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, concatenation

So I'm importing this xlsx file to Python, which contains two columns. I want to unify each column to make a unified string. So the output should be a column where strings from column 1 have merged with strings from column 2. The number of rows will remain the same. Below is my code, nothing crazy as you can see, I was thinking of doing a for loop, any ideas? Many thanks!

```
import xlrd
file_location = "C:/Users/Desktop/manual.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, having two lists:

```
l1 = ["hi", "there"]
l2 = [" Jon", " are"]
```

you can use map for example:

```
list(map(lambda x, y: " ".join((x,y)), l1, l2))
['hi Jon', 'there are']
```

Answer (score 1):

If the xlsx truly only contains 2 columns, then why don't you just read the entire file as raw text, then do a split by newline, instead of using xlrd to load the workbook? The file already has the columns "combined" if you think about it that way...

Could be as simple as:

```
rows = open("filename").read().splitlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

This is easy to do with `pandas`. The following should work (not tested because I don't have your data).

```
import xlrd
import pandas as pd
file_location = "C:/Users/Desktop/manual.xlsx"
workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(file_location)

df = pd.read_excel(workbook)
df['col3'] = df['col1'].astype(str) + df['col2'].astype(str)
```

Comment: That seems like quite the sledgehammer to hammer that nail down

Comment: @DemianBrecht Perhaps. I don't know how much data we're taking about here, and I haven't worked with `xlrd` data before. But I know that pandas operations are fast! The code is also quite readable imo, so I assume the answer can be of some help.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution using `zip` and list comprehension, which is arguably preferred to `map` for readability:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'c']
>>> b = ['b', 'd']
>>> [' '.join(row) for row in zip(a, b)]
['a b', 'c d']
```